# EF: The navigation property is not a declared property on type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am very clueless as to why this isn't working, it seems to work just last week, and I am not seeing any changes to these classes.  Can someone please let me know why I get the error:

> "The navigation property 'Node' is not a declared property on type
>   'NWatchRelation'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from
>   the model and that it is a valid navigation property."

**NWatchRelation Entity**

```
public class NWatchRelation : INWatchRelation
    {
        private NWatchRelation()
        {
        }

        public NWatchRelation(int nodeId, int relatedNodeId)
        {
            NodeId = nodeId;
            RelatedNodeId = relatedNodeId;
        }

        public NWatchRelation(NWatchNode node, NWatchNode relatedNode)
        {
            Node = node;
            RelatedNode = relatedNode;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Foreign Key for Node
        /// </summary>
        public int NodeId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Node
        /// </summary>
        public NWatchNode Node { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Foreign Key for RelatedNode
        /// </summary>
        public int RelatedNodeId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Related Node
        /// </summary>
        public NWatchNode RelatedNode { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Relationship Type
        /// </summary>
        public NWatch.NWatchRelationType RelationType { get; set; }

        INWatchNode INWatchRelation.Node
        {
            get
            {
                return Node;
            }
        }

        INWatchNode INWatchRelation.RelatedNode
        {
            get
            {
                return RelatedNode;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Configuration**

```
// NWatchRelation
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchRelation>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("NWatchRelations");
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchRelation>()
                .HasKey(t => t.Id)
                .Property(t => t.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchRelation>().HasRequired(t => t.Node).
                WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.NodeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<NWatchRelation>().HasRequired(t => t.RelatedNode).
                WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.RelatedNodeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to specify the foreign key attribute if you consider it as navigation property

```
 [ForeignKey("Node"), Column(Order = 0)] 
 public int NodeId { get; set; }
```