# Entity Framework - include ComplexType

Tags: c#

I have an entity class in EF Core 2.0:

```
public class Component : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set}
    public virtual ICollection<ComponentInstance> ComponentInstances { get; set; }
    public virtual Title Title {get ; set;}
}
```

and another `ComplexType` class:

```
[ComplexType]
public class Title
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
}
```

Running this code:

```
var component = _dbContext.Company
                          .Where(x => x.Id == componentId)
                          .Include(x => x.Title)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

throws an exception:

> The property 'Title' is not a navigation property of entity type 'Component'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.

Comment: Please provide the exact exception.

Comment: @brunttoast1
I have tried it but it still gives same exception 
The property 'Title' is not a navigation property of entity type 'Component'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.

Comment: this will help you better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838328/the-property-x-is-not-a-navigation-property-of-entity-type-y

Answer (score 0):

If you are still struggling, you need to ad a `[ForeignKey("")]` to your class. 
Like this:

```
public class Component : BaseModel
    {

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set}
        public virtual ICollection<ComponentInstance> ComponentInstances { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Title")]
        public Title Title {get ; set;}
    }
```

Comment: but Title class is not my entity it is a ComplexType neither it has any primary key .. do u think it will work?

Comment: This is an issue because you will not be able to perform the action without defining foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable problem is that in your `Component` Class, The `Title` Property is not marked as `virtual`.

If it is not `virtual` entity framework cannot `override` it, and will then just ignore it, and does not see it as an entity that it has context to.

Now even when you mark it as virtual, it still does not necessarily mean that entity framework will recognise it as an entity, so in that case you need specify the relationship with [Entity Framework's Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx)

If the relationship of Component class is clear to entity framework, based on  [Convention over Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819164(v=vs.113).aspx), it will not be necessary to explicitly state the relationship with the fluent API.

You obviously also need to have `DbSet<Component>` and `DbSet<Title>` property on your class that inherits from the `DbContext` class

Comment: I have DbSet<Component> in my DbContext type class and vitual is also present there before Title

Comment: @AsifKhan  in your sample code there is no virtual ?

Comment: yes it was not there but after your comment I tried with virtual also

Comment: @AsifKhan I am 100% positive that your problem is that entity framework is not recognising Title as an entity on Component class. So you definitely need to add the virtual, keep it there, and then make sure that Title is  configured properly as an entity for EntityFramework, either through convention of the Fluent API.  as stated in the answer, just marking it as virtual might not be enough.

Comment: @ Gerrie Pretorius I got ur point , but the thing is that my project was in EntityFramework then I migrated to ef core.in EntityFramework Title was just a ComplexType class but not the entity it was working fine without the lazy loading .. but I want to know that is it possible in ef core and if possible then how can I do this