# The property 'a' is not a navigation property of entity type 'b'. Why not?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to load a list of product identifier `Label`s (i.e. names of product identifiers, such as "EAN", "Product number", etc.) from `ProductIdentifiers` with this query:

```
ICollection<ProductIdentifierInType> typeIds =
            _context.ProductIdentifiersInTypes
            .Include(t => t.Identifier.Label)
            .OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder).ToList();
```

VS gives me intellisense for `t.Identifier.Label`. The solution compiles fine. This is the runtime error I get:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'Label' is not a navigation property of entity type 'ProductIdentifier'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.

Here are the relevant model classes:

```
public class ProductIdentifierInType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public ProductIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }
    public ProductType Type { get; set; }
}

public class ProductIdentifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductIdentifierInType> TypeIdentifiers { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public class MyStoreContext : DbContext // IdentityDbContext
{
    public MyStoreContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    // some unrelated tables ...

    public DbSet<ProductIdentifierInType> ProductIdentifiersInTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductIdentifier> ProductIdentifiers { get; set; }

    // some more, unrelated tables ...
}
```

I have tried inheriting from `IdentityDbContext` like the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838328/the-property-x-is-not-a-navigation-property-of-entity-type-y), but that didn't make any difference.

What is wrong?

Comment: *The property 'Label' is not a navigation property* tells exactly what's wrong.

Comment: The only navigation property you have on ProductIdentifierInType is Type. Include only works on Navigation properties. Is there some code missing as well? What is t.identifier ?

Comment: @illug Oh, my bad! I accidently deleted some code when pasting into this question. I have updated it now. `Identifier` is the navigation link from `ProductIdentifierInType` to `ProductIdentifier`. `Label` is found within `ProductIdentifier`.

Comment: @GertArnold I accidently deleted some rather important code before: `public ProductIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }` It's there now. It's the navigation link from `ProductIdentifierInType` to `ProductIdentifier`. Isn't that properly linked? `Label` is found in `ProductIdentifier`.

Comment: I assumed that. It's simple: 'Label' is not a navigation property.

Comment: @GertArnold I don't get it. `ProductIdentifierInType` has `Identifier` as navigation. Under `Identifier`, we find `Id`, `Label` and `SortOrder`. Why isn't `Label` a navigation property?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1262307/861716

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the Include is for the Navigation property only.

Instead of doing `.Include(t => t.Identifier.Label)` try to do only `.Include(t => t.Identifier)`

Then access the Label property using the List.

Comment: Ha! Thank you! :)